# Inversion sum is not correct using Stream.reduce

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

Inversion sum is not correct using Stream.reduce, what is going wrong here ?

```
double[] array = {1.0, 2.0};
double iunversionSum = Arrays.stream(array).reduce(0.0, (a, b) -> Double.sum(1.0 / a, 1.0 / b));
```

output is .5 but expected is 1.5 (1/1 + 1/2)

Comment: `Arrays.stream(array6).map(d->Double.valueOf(1/d)).reduce(0.0, Double::sum);`

Comment: @HadiJ or just `Arrays.stream(array6).map(d->1/d).sum()`

Comment: If you want to go with the reduce operation: `Arrays.stream(array).reduce(0.0, (a, b) -> Double.sum(a, 1.0 / b))`

Comment: @Holger why not make an answer to suggest that or possibly `double val = DoubleStream.of(array).map(d -> 1.0 / d).sum();` ?

Comment: @nullpointer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54144350/2711488) is sufficient. For an existing array, I’d use `Array.stream`, not the varargs method `DoubleStream.of`.

Comment: @ThomasKläger `(a, b) -> Double.sum(a, 1.0 / b)` is not associative.

Comment: @Holger ya, the `DoubleStream.of` eventually uses the same method.

Comment: @Holger you are correct - I was thinking along the `collect` operation, which does not require associativity

Comment: @ThomasKläger that’s because the function has been split into an accumulator function and a combiner function for `collect`. You can achieve the same via `.boxed() .reduce(0.0, (a, b) -> a + 1.0 / b, Double::sum)`, unfortunately not directly on `DoubleStream`.

Comment: @Holger if I use for loop like: double inversionSum =0.0; for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {inversionSum += 1.0 / array[i]; } it gives different precision than Arrays.stream(array6).map(d->1/d).sum(), any idea why ?

Comment: @Vipin `DoubleStream.sum()` may use an algorithm to reduce errors. In case of OpenJDK, it’s the [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Comment: @Vipin By the way, I am unable to reproduce the *different precision*, could you share more details around it?

Comment: @nullpointer I suppose, `array6` is not the array from the question. Generally, floating point math results depend on the order, therefore, the contracts must allow some small differences, to ever consider a double function associative. Otherwise, parallel evaluation would be impossible for `double` operations.

Comment: @nullpointer you can reproduce this with double[] array = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}

Comment: @Holger i will read more about DoubleStream.sum() how can i stop precision loss , but looks like I should go with for loop for now.

Comment: @Vipin `DoubleStream.sum()` is *more precise*. To stay with your example `1 + ½ + ⅓ + ¼ == 25/12` and the result of `DoubleStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).map(d->1/d).sum()` is closer to that than the result of your `for` loop, in fact, you can’t get closer to the correct result with `double` values, as `DoubleStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).map(d->1/d).sum() == 25.0/12.0` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think using `map()` it could be simplier.

```
double inversionSum = Arrays.stream(arr).map(val -> 1 / val).sum();
```

Comment: This is working solution, I am worried about precision loss in this compared to for loop solution :--> double[] array = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};  double inversionSum =0.0; for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {inversionSum += 1.0 / array[i]; }

Comment: @Vipin as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144110/inversion-sum-is-not-correct-using-stream-reduce?noredirect=1#comment95122735_54144110), there’s a difference, but that doesn’t imply that your `for` loop is more precise.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your reduce is: Double.sum(1.0 / a, 1.0 / b), starting the series with 0.0. Now check why your outcome is .5.

Use Double.sum(a, 1.0 / b), if you want to use reduce.